# How to fix "TypeError fit_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samples_per_epoch'"

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

defining the samples per epoch = 1212 and nb_val_samples = 20 nb_epoch=20, validation_data=test_set, nb_val_samples=300 then in am getting the error

Answer (score 0):

Note that fit_generator() is deprecated. You can use fit() directly with Python generators.

An example for a batch size of 1

```
history = model.fit(generate_data(), steps_per_epoch=len(x_train), epochs=100, 
callbacks = [callback],class_weight={0:4, 1:1}, validation_data=generate_val(), 
 validation_steps=len(x_test))
```